# Phone extremely slow, even after factory reset

Tags: samsung, lagging, samsung-galaxy-j5

I have a Samsung Galaxy J5 2016. It's gotten extremely slow and buggy (>10 crashes a day, waiting more than 30 seconds to open default apps, ...).

I've done a factory reset, with removal of all data, including SD card. And... It's just the same.

I'm already looking around for a new phone, but I'm wondering what can cause this?
When I google why phones get slower over time, they point to more and heavier apps. But this doesn't explain my case.

What can cause this behavior, even after a reset?

Comment: Old phone have old unmaintained Android versions installed with a lot of vulnerabilities. Apps can therefore use these vulnerabilities and install malware as system app, hence factory reset has no effect. Alternatively your CPU may be partially defect or the heat transportation does not fully work and the CPU overheats.

Answer (score 1):

The most common culprits for slowing down your phone is accumulating background apps and hardware degradation. Since you've factory reset your phone, that rules out the first.

Flash memory in your phone degrades as you repeatedly write data, but this is a slow process. Eventually you will have sectors of memory fail from physical wear or accumulation of electrons which makes them unreadable.

Same thing happened to my Samsung Note 4. Was blazing quick when I first got it, now its sluggish, even after a reset.

Btw, check out Cycle (https://cyclephones.com)

It lets you stream an android emulator from a server to your phone so that you can run any app smoothly.

Full disclosure: I run Cycle, but I'd use it even if I didn't. There isn't a good solution to a slow phone other than buying a new one.

Comment: Afaik flash degrades by its increasing probability of a hardware error, but not by its writing speed.